# android-apt-compiler: [google-play-services_lib] No Build Tools in the Android SDK

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

I'm trying to import existing Android project that uses the play-services lib into the Android Studio.
When building the app I get this error:

```
android-apt-compiler: [google-play-services_lib] No Build Tools in the Android SDK.
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Well it just happened that I tested android studio and the SDK was updated at the same time :) I guess I confused by the new experience.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is the new Android SDK Build-tools package installed on your computer?

[image: Android SDK Build-tools]